# Is there something wrong with sed for the mac terminal?

Tags: sed

I am having trouble making sed work on my mac terminal.  The original version I have is /usr/bin/sed
I want to see what version it is so I type:

```
sed --version
```

I get the following output:

> /usr/bin/sed: illegal option -- - usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i
>   extension] [file ...]
>          sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

My man page is for sed 4.2 and that should have a --version option

I then installed to /usr/local/bin by downloading from gnu ftp http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/

I then run `/usr/local/bin/sed` --version and still get same output as with original version.  I am completely confused, can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: It seems like even though *which sed* gives me */usr/local/bin/sed* the command *sed* is still running */usr/bin/sed*, consequently */usr/local/bin/sed* is not being invoked. If I invoke with full path it works as expected.

I guess question is now why *which sed* is giving me */usr/local/bin/sed* yet the command run when I type *sed* is */usr/bin/sed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/usr/bin/sed` is the BSD sed which does not support `--version` as your error statement shows. The man page for it is `/usr/share/man/man1/sed.1.gz`, when I read that there is no mention of a version at all, however the date on the man page is May 10, 2005.

I am thinking you have an incorrect man page. Most probably a `MANPATH` that is looking somewhere else first.

As for why `/usr/local/bin/sed` which you are saying is GNU sed does not honor the `--version` I am not sure about. Can you give more detail about this?

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  I have just rebooted my computer and it now works properly. I did not know about the BSD sed default for MAC so thanks. I think when I installed GNU Sed I corrupted something.

Comment: @mcheema: The `--version` and `--help` options are for GNU programs that use GNU `getopt_long()` to process options.  They are almost universal in programs that do use `getopt_long()`.  They are not supported in that form by programs using plain `getopt()` — which covers many programs not written to the GNU coding standards.  Sometimes, programs accept `-V` (or `-v`) to print version information; sometimes, programs accept `-h` or `-?` to print help.  However, there's no compulsion to do so and many don't.

Comment: thanks  @Jonathan Leffler. I am mostly an R programmer but have recently been inspired to dust of awk and sed after reading a Brian Kernighan interview as in many use cases of dealing with messy data I find these tools pretty useful.